# NMinimize behaving unexpectedly

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to solve the minimax problem that I posted below. If I set c1 to 1.0 NMinimize gives me a result as expected. If I however change it slightly, even by a miniscule amount I get error messages. One of those says that the function value is not a number at {a,b,r1} = {1.14946,0.984114,0.0875131}. If I plug these values into the max function manually though, I get a result. In other error messages it complains that the comparison of some numbers is invalid and shows values containing complex numbers and minus infinity, but I don't know how it is getting these numbers. I don't know if NMinimize generates its result differently as it would be if I just test varying parameters manually, but I cannot get it to work correctly. So why does NMinimize not work if I set c1 to a value different than 1?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
r[a_, b_, u_] := {a Cos[u], b Sin[u]}
chord[c_, u1_, u2_] := EuclideanDistance[r[c, 1, u1], r[c, 1, u2]]
rad2D[width_, rad_] := ArcLength[r[width, 1, u], {u, 0, rad}]
arc[width_, rad1_, rad2_] := ArcLength[r[width, 1, u], {u, rad1, rad2}]
edge[width_, u_] := EuclideanDistance[{0, 0}, r[width, 1, u]]
E0r[a_, b_, c_, r_] := 
 edge[c, r] + arc[c, a - b + r, Pi + r] + chord[c, a - b + r, a + r]
E1r[a_, b_, c_, r_] := 
 edge[c, r] + arc[c, a + r, Pi + r] + chord[c, a + r, -a + r]
E2r[a_, b_, c_, r_] := 
 edge[c, r] + arc[c, a + r, Pi + r] + chord[c, a - b + r, a + r] + 
  SP[a, b, c, r] + chord[c, a - b + r, a - b + SP[a, b, c, r] + r]
equation[a_, b_, c_, r_, g_] := 
 arc[c, -a + b + r, 
   a + r] - (chord[c, -a + r, b - a + r] + 
    arc[c, b - a - g + r, b - a + r])
SP[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_, r_?NumericQ] := 
 p /. FindRoot[equation[a, b, c, r, p], {p, a - b}, Evaluated -> False]
c1 := 1.1

NMinimize[{Max[E0r[a, b, c1, r1], E1r[a, b, c1, r1], 
   E2r[a, b, c1, r1]], 
  a > Pi/3 && Cos[a] + Cos[a - b/2] > 1}, {{a, 1.1, 1.2}, {b, 0.9, 
   1.0}, {r1, 0.0, Pi/2}}]
```

Comment: Not an answer,  but a couple of observations:  Note that some of your functions take a *long* time to evaluate, for example `ContourPlot[E2r[a, b, 1, 1], {a, Pi/3, 4 Pi}, {b, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]` . You can save some time by not repeatedly computing arclength, but just doing it once:  `arcSymbolic = Simplify[
  ArcLength[ {width Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, rad}],
  Assumptions -> width > 0]` and then `arclength = Function[{width,rad},Evaluate[arcSymbolic]]`  and then `arclength[1,2]` will be much faster.

Comment: I tried working on your code, but gave up because I couldn't follow which variable was doing what.  I'd recommend  more descriptive variable names such as `a  -> semiAxis1` etc. Not that it matters, but it is just helpful

Comment: You might find `RegionPlot[
 a > Pi/3 && Cos[a] + Cos[a - b/2] > 1, {a, Pi/3, 4 Pi}, {b, -2 Pi, 
  2 Pi}]` to be visually helpful.

Comment: Also, I am not finding the variable specification `{{a, 1.1, 1.2}, {b, 0.9, 1.0}, {r1, 0.0, Pi/2} }` in the documentation.  What are you trying to do here? Give it initial values (if so, see Method) or give a constraint?

Comment: Will keep that in mind to give variables better names in the future! Yes, I am trying to give them initial values, as for similar problems NMinimize was unable to find initial values and that had helped before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A liberal sprinkling of _?NumericQ makes the problem go away:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
r[a_, b_, u_] := {a Cos[u], b Sin[u]}
chord[c_, u1_, u2_] := EuclideanDistance[r[c, 1, u1], r[c, 1, u2]]
rad2D[width_?NumericQ, rad_?NumericQ] := 
 ArcLength[r[width, 1, u], {u, 0, rad}]
arc[width_, rad1_?NumericQ, rad2_?NumericQ] := 
 ArcLength[r[width, 1, u], {u, rad1, rad2}]
edge[width_, u_] := EuclideanDistance[{0, 0}, r[width, 1, u]]
E0r[a_, b_, c_, r_] := 
 edge[c, r] + arc[c, a - b + r, Pi + r] + chord[c, a - b + r, a + r]
E1r[a_, b_, c_, r_] := 
 edge[c, r] + arc[c, a + r, Pi + r] + chord[c, a + r, -a + r]
E2r[a_, b_, c_, r_] := 
 edge[c, r] + arc[c, a + r, Pi + r] + chord[c, a - b + r, a + r] + 
  SP[a, b, c, r] + chord[c, a - b + r, a - b + SP[a, b, c, r] + r]
equation[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, r_?NumericQ, 
  g_?NumericQ] := 
 arc[c, -a + b + r, 
   a + r] - (chord[c, -a + r, b - a + r] + 
    arc[c, b - a - g + r, b - a + r])
SP[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_, r_?NumericQ] := 
 p /. FindRoot[equation[a, b, c, r, p], {p, a - b}, Evaluated -> False]
```

So this works:

```
objective[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c1_?NumericQ, r1_?NumericQ] := 
 Max[E0r[a, b, c1, r1], E1r[a, b, c1, r1], E2r[a, b, c1, r1]]
```

and to monitor progress:

```
Dynamic[currentValue]
```

this will return in answer, but it takes a while:

```
With[{c = 1},
 NMinimize[{objective[a, b, c, r1], 
   a > Pi/3 && Cos[a] + Cos[a - b/2] > 1}, {{a, 1.1, 1.2}, {b, 0.9, 
    1.0}, {r1, 0.0, Pi/2} },
  EvaluationMonitor :> (currentValue = objective[a, b, c, r1])]
 ]
```

This no longer throws errors, but I lost patience waiting:

```
With[{c = 1.1},
 NMinimize[{objective[a, b, c, r1], 
   a > Pi/3 && Cos[a] + Cos[a - b/2] > 1}, {{a, 1.1, 1.2}, {b, 0.9, 
    1.0}, {r1, 0.0, Pi/2} },
  EvaluationMonitor :> (currentValue = objective[a, b, c, r1])]
 ]
```

The comments above about computing something symbolically first will--I think--speed things up.

Comment: This solution, combined with using -EllipticE[rad1, 1 - width^2] + EllipticE[rad2, 1 - width^2] to calculate the ArcLength as provided in the other answer did the job.

Answer (score 6):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

r[a_, b_, u_] := {a Cos[u], b Sin[u]}
chord[c_, u1_, u2_] := EuclideanDistance[r[c, 1, u1], r[c, 1, u2]]
rad2D[width_, rad_] := ArcLength[r[width, 1, u], {u, 0, rad}]
```

The [`ArcLength`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcLength.html) can be evaluated symbolically in terms of [`EllipticE`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticE.html)

```
arc[width_, rad1_, rad2_] = ArcLength[r[width, 1, u], {u, rad1, rad2}]

(* -EllipticE[rad1, 1 - width^2] + EllipticE[rad2, 1 - width^2] *)

edge[width_, u_] := EuclideanDistance[{0, 0}, r[width, 1, u]]
E0r[a_, b_, c_, r_] := 
 edge[c, r] + arc[c, a - b + r, Pi + r] + chord[c, a - b + r, a + r]
E1r[a_, b_, c_, r_] := 
 edge[c, r] + arc[c, a + r, Pi + r] + chord[c, a + r, -a + r]
E2r[a_, b_, c_, r_] := 
 edge[c, r] + arc[c, a + r, Pi + r] + chord[c, a - b + r, a + r] + 
  SP[a, b, c, r] + chord[c, a - b + r, a - b + SP[a, b, c, r] + r]
```

Since you are only dealing with real numbers, `Abs[x] == Sqrt[x^2]`

```
equation[a_, b_, c_, r_, g_] = 
  arc[c, -a + b + r, 
      a + r] - (chord[c, -a + r, b - a + r] + 
       arc[c, b - a - g + r, b - a + r]) /. Abs[x_] :> Sqrt[x^2] // 
   FullSimplify;

SP[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ,
  c_?NumericQ, r_?NumericQ] :=
 p /. FindRoot[equation[a, b, c, r, p], {p, a - b}, Evaluated -> False]

With[{c1 = 1},
 NMinimize[{Max[E0r[a, b, c1, r1], E1r[a, b, c1, r1], E2r[a, b, c1, r1]], 
   a > Pi/3, Cos[a] + Cos[a - b/2] > 1}, 
  {{a, 11/10, 12/10}, {b, 9/10, 1}, {r1, 0, Pi/2}}]]

(* {4.81854, {a -> 1.14193, b -> 0.925792, r1 -> 0.994877}} *)

With[{c1 = 11/10},
 NMinimize[{Max[E0r[a, b, c1, r1], E1r[a, b, c1, r1], E2r[a, b, c1, r1]], 
   a > Pi/3, Cos[a] + Cos[a - b/2] > 1}, 
  {{a, 11/10, 12/10}, {b, 9/10, 1}, {r1, 0, Pi/2}}]]

(* {5.0505, {a -> 1.0472, b -> 0.868468, r1 -> 1.1101}} *)
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that the value of $a$ that minimizes the function when $c_1=1.1$ is essentially the lower limit for $a$:  $\pi/3$.